# Using non-ASCII characters in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I want set the UserName to Chinese Word, the document

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
   options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
});
```

I want to set the word to Chinese word
like this

```
var user = new IdentityUser { Email = "admin@xxx.com", UserName = "管理员" };
var result= userManager.CreateAsync(user, "admin123456"); // 等待异步方法执行完毕
```

the result is
Id = 1, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "Failed : InvalidUserName"

Comment: So... you set the allowed username characters to ASCII... then you try to create a username with non-ASCII characters... and that username is rejected, **exactly as it should be**... what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Additionally, what backing database are you using? You need to ensure your database and library support Unicode characters - so don't use `varchar`, only use `nvarchar` (unless you're using [SQL Server 2019 with `varchar` UTF-8 support working](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928) _and thoroughly tested_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of ASP.NET Core Identity. You could do the following to disable validation:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
});
```

Besides, change your code like below:

```
//add await....
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "AD@admin123456");
```

**Note:**

The default passwords contain an uppercase character, lowercase character, a digit, and a non-alphanumeric character. Passwords must be at least six characters long.

If you do not custom password validation, `admin123456` here is not valid, you still need an uppercase character and a non-alphanumeric character.